# How to draw a chart using either angularjs and Angular4

Tags: angularjs, angular, charts

[Added image for Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khUlf.jpg)I want to draw a `Line chart` or `Point chart` in which x-axis has multiple row and every row can have multiple value on the basis of user selection and y-axis has one value only.

Please make me understand with the help of example.

I am giving an example here. Suppose I have two material value, every material has multiple subcategory, every subcategory has multiple set of value Then x-axis has 3 rows for material, sub category, and multiple values of that sub-category. I need help to draw this chart on front side.skill using angularjs/angular4.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is not a coding service, we're here to help you solve a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the chart.js library, or google charts. Here are the links:
-[Chart JS](https://www.chartjs.org/)
- [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

Comment: It's not a solution.i want multiple row in x-axis not a single row.